# Is "expanding" an adjective?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, adjectives

I came across this sentence on a [Britannica page](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Roman-Jakobson):

> The titles of Jakobson’s works indicate the **expanding** scope of his research

Why is *expanding* used here instead of *expansive*? Is *expanding* a commonly used adjective? Any difference from *expansive*?

Comment: No, "expanding" doesn't have the lexical properties of an adjective. It's best seen as a verb phrase functioning as a modifier of "scope". Semantically, "expanding" means that the scope of his research is still growing, while "expansive" implies that it has reached a large size.

Comment: @BillJ the way I was taught grammar, "expanding" is the present-participle form of the verb "expand", and thus could be used three different ways: 1) to form the present progressive tense 2) As a participial noun 3) As a participial adjective.  This is #3.

Comment: Maybe I'm off base here, but I believe for this to act as an adjective (in the sense of only describing the noun), the word choice would have to be `expandable`, that way it could speak to the potential type of scope, and not the action that is taking place, or has taken place upon the scope. I'm not saying this is the only possibility, however for strict clarity of adjective vs verb, I believe that it is note worthy.

Comment: On another note... What if this sentence was rendered this way: `The titles of Jakobson's works indicate the scope of his research **is** expanding.` I believe that this may have been Lambie's comment. `is` takes on the verb (state of being) and `expanding` still expresses the progressive "action" state of the research; Because it speaks to its state, it can still be equated to describing the noun `scope`.

Answer (score 16):

Expansive means the scope of his research is **already large**, while expanding means the scope of his research is still **continuing to grow larger.**

Answer (score 7):

**Expansive** means "very large", while **expanding** means "becoming progressively larger".

If the scope of Jakobson's work is **expansive**, then we'd expect the titles of his works to cover many different subjects - that is, the scope is very large.

If the scope of Jakobson's work is **expanding**, then we'd expect later titles to cover more subject areas than the earlier ones do - that is, the scope gets larger over time.

Comment: This is the right answer, but let me build on it.  The concept being discussed in the article is presented in the past continuous tense.  In other words, at the time the aticle is referencing with this sentence, Jakobson's research was incomplete.  Because you can match the adjective with the tense, you should.  Thus "expanding" (an ongoing action) is used.  Had the sentence been describing his research at the end of his life, it could use "expansive" (past simple, the action is complete to the adjective should be, too) to describe the final volume of his research.

Comment: I just do not understand comments that misquote a question. The question is in the present simple. There  is no past continuous tense here at all. Expanding here is a simple adjective. Gerunds in English can be adjectives.

Comment: @Lambie, I apologize if I've offended you.  Please review how the adjective "expanding" is being used in the Britannica article.  You'll discover that the context of the sentence (not the question) is past continuous: a statement of condition at a past point in the article subject's life.  I noted in my comment that I was discussing the concept and did not realize I needed to be specific that it was not a discussion of specific sentence structure.  Note that the adjective "Expansive" would have been inappropriate for the article author's purposes due to the author's context.

Answer (score 2):

Looking up [*expanding*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expanding) on Wiktionary we see:

### Verb

#### expanding

[present](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#present_tense) [participle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#participle) of [expand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expand#English)

---

The page for [*Glossary: participle*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#participle) says:

#### [participle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/participle)

A form of a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#verb) that may function as an [adjective](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#adjective) or [noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#noun). [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language) has two types of participles: the [present](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#present) participle and the [past](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#past) participle. In other languages, also [future](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#future), [perfect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#perfect), [future perfect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#future_perfect) participles.

---

So, to answer the question title, **all** participles, including *expanding*, may act as adjectives.

*expanding* means it's still growing (**present** participle). The main meaning of [*expansive*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expansive) is "comprehensive".